# Query being fired but insert not reflected in DB

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate, persistence

I am using Hibernate to persist an entity object in an Oracle DB:

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        TABLE_NAME
        (COLUMNS..) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

This is what i'm getting after setting "show_sql" to "true". There are no kinds of exception and systrace & debug shows everything running smoothly. I've re-checked the mapping & config also and everything looks good; I've checked the DB also.

The problem is that the insert is not reflecting in the table! What maybe the issue! I've re-checked every setting, mapping, etc etc.. but I cannot understand where is it going wrong, please help!

-EDIT-

Yes, I've committed as well! :|

Comment: how about to commit after insert?

Comment: yes, I have committed as well! :|

Answer (score 3):

I would check that you're connecting to the database that you think you are connecting to, and to the user also. You might try adding a constraint on the table to prevent the row that you're testing with being inserted to see if you can provoke an error.

If you've checked these issues then the problem presumably lies outside of the database.

Comment: Ya, I've done those! I've not checked with a constraint though, that was a good point, I'll check n update.

Comment: No change even after introducing a constraint!

Comment: I think that you're not even connecting to the database then, or that query is not actually getting executed

Comment: Connecting, getting executed also, the only explanation I can think of is somehow it is not committing & I don't know why or how!

Comment: The presence of the constraint ought to have detected that situation, unless an error is being surpressed.

Comment: Um ... maybe you can turn on logging/tracing in SQL*Net on the client side to see if the connection is taking place. I have a feeling that it would highlight commits also, but I'm no expert on that stuff.

Comment: This has been escalated, we are testing the other dependencies now, few more such issues have been raised. :[

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some other oracle user session obtained a lock on a table you are trying to insert in?

Comment: In that case there should have been an exception!

Comment: Hmmm, i am never get an exception in that case. Using hibernate 3.6.9 btw

Comment: No one has a lock, I double checked. We are running tests, hope to find the cause, most probably in our internal system only.